# Grails + jQuery: formRemote onSuccess

Tags: jquery, forms, grails

I'm struggling with the `<g:formRemote/> onSuccess` method and how I could call my custom `JavaScript` function properly.

I have the following `formRemote` element:

```
<g:formRemote name="userSearchRemoteForm"
                      url="[controller: 'userSearch', action: 'ajaxFindUser']"
                      onLoading="jQuery('#userSearchSubContainerHeadLoaderImage').show()"
                      onSuccess="createUserTable(data)"
                      onComplete="jQuery('#userSearchSubContainerHeadLoaderImage').hide()">
....</g:formRemote>
```

in debug mode I see, that the `Controller` function `ajaxFindUser` is called and returns a valid JSON object like this (from the `console` with `prettyPrint == true`):

```
{"success": {
"376440": {
  "phone": "",
  "email": "janeDoe@test.com",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "firstname": "Jane"
},
"4146": {
  "phone": "555-123456789",
  "email": "johnDoe@test.com",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "firstname": "John"
}
}}
```

my `JavaScript` function `createUserTable` looks like this:

```
function createGuestTable(data) {
console.log(data);
}
```

all I see in my WebDev Tool is the following response:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/GrailsTest001/userSearch/ajaxFindUser 404 (Not Found)
```

and my function is never called. I also tried to call the `JavaScript function` in `onSuccess` like this:

```
onSuccess="createUserTable()"
```

but I still get the same result...

what am I doing wrong here?

---

**Edit:** to clear things out - here's my `Controller` function:

```
def ajaxFindUser(UserSearchCommand userSearchCommand) {
    println("... in ajaxFindUser()")
    def result = [:]

    if (userSearchCommand.hasErrors()) {
        result['fail'] = "Error in search values!"
    } else {
        println("... creating values for search...")
        def user = (User) session.getValue(theUser)
        def inputMap = createInputMap(userSearchCommand)

        def foundUsers = userSearchService.findUser(user.connectionID, user.language, inputMap)

        if (foundUsers == null) {
            println("... search returned NULL!")
            result = [:]
            result['fail'] = userSearchService.getError()
        } else {
            println("... search returned VALUES!!")
            result['success'] = foundUsers
        }
    }

    def jResult = result as JSON

    println(".... returning JSON: ${jResult.toString(true)}")
    return jResult
}
```

Comment: means page not found, whats result if you put this link directly in your browser address bar?

Comment: but why did the controller function get called if it is not reachable? do I have to `return` something else than a `JSON` object? do I have to tell the controller to not `render` anything specifically? indeed, I got also a 404 if I try to type the url into the browser, but for me that's clear because all the controller function does is to take a `Command` object and return a `JSON` object either on success or failure, so it can't be reachable - or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh my!
I was facing the problem but didn't recognize it would be a problem at all...

I just changed the last line of my `ajaxFindUser` function from

```
return jResult
```

to

```
render jResult
```

with the following `onSuccess` parameter

```
onSuccess="createUserTable(data)"
```

and all is working well!!

sorry for that...